# Unsubscribe users based on UUID

Tags: android, pubnub

I am beginner to PubNub, my question is when multiple users subscribed to a channel can I unsubscribe one of these users form the server side based on uuid? if not, Can you please help me doing this.

my project is depending on multiple users subscribed to one channel where the server side is subscribed on the presence channel and listening to all statuses, I need the server side to unsubscribe any user at any time?

Comment: What type of research have you done so far?

Comment: Actually most of my research was on API documentation on pubnub.com, what I found that the unsubscribe function is taking a channel_name param only. what I need is to unsubscribe user based on uuid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Remote Control Client Unsubscribe

There are a couple of ways to implement this. One provides the ability to send a signal to the client to unsubscribe and the other allows for complete server side control. Using a *chat room* example, I will describe how to accomplish this. All links to [PubNub docs are to the Node SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) but you can check [the docs for any other SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/) as required.

### Client Side Unsubscribe

You can use *signal* messages to cause the client to do actions *automagically*.

First, you should have every client subscribe to a channel that is unique to the client. The channel name can include the user's UUID, like `ch-1234-5678-9ABC`. Whatever naming convention you choose will suffice as long as you have a way to map the client to that channel.

When your server determines that a client should unsubscribe from a channel, you can send a *command signal* on that client's private channel to perform the action. The message might like this:

```
{'command':'leave', 'channel':'chat-abc'}
```

When a client receives a message like this, your client logic will perform an `unsubscribe` on channel `chat-abc`. No action by the end user (the human) is required. Sort of a *remote control unsubscribe*, or whatever action you need to have the client execute.

You could have just as easily sent the *command signal* on the channel that you want the client to unsubscribe from, but then all clients subscribed to that channel would get the message and your client code would have to filter on UUID. Not exactly the most efficient way but definitely another option. Useful if you need to have many or all clients on the channel unsubscribe. You could pass a list of UUIDs and each client just checks to see if their UUID is in the list and execute the action if it is. Your message payload might look this:

```
{'command':'leave', 'uuids':['1234-5678-9ABC','DEFG-HIJK-LMNO','9876-5432-1ZYX']}
```

No channel needs to be specified since it would apply to the channel that your server published the message on.

### Remove Channel from Channel Group

The above will work and is pretty simple but requires code on the server and the client to make it all work. With [Channel Groups](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/stream-controller#channel_groups), the server gets to have all the fun without the client getting involved, except to initially subscribe to the Channel Group in question.

Each client will subscribe their very own Channel Group (just like the private channel above) instead of directly to a channel. Let's call the channel group `cg-1234-5678-9ABC`. So again, we want a way to map the channel group to a particular user, so we use the UUID as part of the name.

For every client that needs to be a part of the chat room, which is on `chat-abc` like before, [this channel will be added to each users' private channel group](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/api-reference#add_channel_to_group). Doing this from the server has the effect of subscribing the client to that channel and any other channel you add to those channel groups.

When your server determines that a user needs to be unsubscribed from a channel, it can simply [remove that channel from that user's private channel group](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/api-reference#cg_remove_channels). And that's all there is to it.

### Security Control with Access Manager

Now all of the above is cool, but it isn't very secure. Because if a *curious user* wanted to, they could write a little code to just subscribe to the channel (any channel or channel group) or add the channel to their channel group and even publish to any channel they wanted to (even a channel that no one is listening to).

To guard against this, you need [Access Manager](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pam-security) and have your server grant `read` permission to the channel or channel group that the clients need to subscribe to and `write` permission to the channel that the clients need to publish to.

For channel groups, your clients only need `read` access to the channel group(s). All channels added to those channel groups will inherit the `read` permission but not any `write` permissions to publish - that has to be granted per user per channel.

Your server has to have the `manage` permission for the channel groups it needs to add & remove channel to and from (which it can granted to itself when it needs that permission per channel group). When a client is forced to leave a channel (by whichever means you choose from above: channel unsubscribe or channel group remove channel), you would also remove the `read` and `write` permission for that user's auth-key.

I purposely left out the details of Access Manager granting and revoking because it is sufficiently covered in our docs or in other SO threads and PubNub blogs. But contact [PubNub Support](http://www.pubnub.com/support) if you need more assistance with Access Manager implementation.

Comment: Thanks Craig, actually we will go with the solution of publishing leave message with uuid and handling the unsubscribe from user side, but we are facing a problem when user is in timeout status where user can't receive messages. Can you please suggest other solutions for handling the unsubscribe with timeout status?

To make everything clear, our main purpose from the unsubscribe is to stop receiving user's statuses on the presence channel.

Comment: If they timeout then they are not subscribed (as you probably know). You would only get a join if they then come back online and subscribe to the channel again. This is where Access Manager provides the ability to prevent a client from subscribing or publishing to a channel. Otherwise, you would have detect that they joined and then force them to unsubscribe again. But prevents them from subscribing again later? Access Manager! :) And Access Manager add-on is FREE forever for all account plans (paid or not). It's that important.